# How can I generate the cucumber json report with karate

Tags: json, cucumber, karate

```
At the moment, only hml cucumber reports are generated and also karate reports in json format but I can't get the Cucumber reports in json format to be able to use them in an integration Help!
```

The runner file looks like this
`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOidr.png)

```
I have the configuration that you showed and the Cucumber reporting dependency, I don't know what else I need
```

```
since I am only getting the html report from cucumber and I need the json
```

```
<configuration>
    <projectName>karate_automatione</projectName>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
    <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `karate-reports` folder. Any files with the `*.json` extension are in Cucumber JSON format.

But each `Feature` will have a separate JSON output. But most tools that handle the Cucumber JSON are able to process multiple at a time.

Comment: hello thanks for answering!! if i have json reports there in that folder but they don't match cucumber json format

Comment: @NAYELYSIBAÑEZ that doesn't make sense to me. follow this process so we can investigate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue